# использование событий навигации во вью модели

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

от более опытных людей узнал, что в полноценном MVVM события типа OnNavigatedFrom / To необходимо также использовать во вью-модели, а не в код бихайнде. Как можно их переопределить, чтобы они стали доступны из вью модели конкретно для его вью ?

Comment: чаще всего вам ответят, что нужно использовать фреймворк, а вот какой - зависит от предпочтений (моя прелесть :)) отвечающего. Навигация это работа View. Значит для доступа к этому функционалу во ViewModel вам понадобится доступ  к View через интерфейс, в котором описаны методы навигации.

Comment: продолжение. Это также как работа из вьюмодели с базой данных или файловой системой (прочитать - записать), навигация, информационные сообщения пользователю (MessageBox) со всем этим вьюмодел должна работать через интерфейсы, а не напрямую.